# Python connetion to smtp server fails

Tags: python, smtp, icmp

I am creating an application in python which will send a mail in background via a local smtp server. For this I am using the basic `smtplib`, but there is an issue with the smtp server, users are able to browse the mail-website but are not able to ping it, after some research I found that it might be the issue of [ICMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) protocol setting on the server which is blocking it.
Because of which the `socket.connect()` command fails when it tries to connect with the server.

Question 1: Is my theory right, could it be because of ICMP or something else would be wrong?

Question 2: Is there is any workaround, that I can do to make the emailing work?

Thanks.

Comment: So you can not ping the smtp server?

Comment: No I can not ping it, but i tried to get `fqdn` by python and i was getting it right.

Comment: A ping has nothing to do with tcp. they are independent.